# How do I place this object inside an array

Tags: reactjs

How do I place this object inside an array: [Dog API](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/documentation/). Is an object inside another object. I'm trying to set setBreeds(breedsList.message) but does not work.

```js
const basicUrl = `https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/`
const listUrl = `list/all`

const Home = () => {
  // uses state to store the list of breeds
  const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState([])

  // fetch the list of breeds
  const fetchBreeds = async () => {
    let url
    url = `${basicUrl}${listUrl}`
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const breedsList = await response.json()
    setBreeds(breedsList)
  }

  // useeffect to mount the fetchBreeds function
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchBreeds()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {/* // maps  */}
      {breeds.map((breed) => console.log(breed))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct modification of state arrays in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do like this

```
setBreeds(prevState => [...prevState, breedsList.message])
```

Comment: Let me know here if you face any problem

Comment: Thanks!! When I map {breeds} I get this error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {affenpinscher, african, airedale, akita, appenzeller, australian,

Comment: That can happen when your ```breedsList.message``` is not holding a single value. It is adding an object.

Comment: That is a mapping or iterating issues not a state update issues. Can you show how you are rendering the state. Because in console log it won't give the error you mentioned. When you are trying to render an object that time it is giving the error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is what you are asking for but the following function turns the json response into a list of breed names. You could transform the object and then call setBreeds.

```js
function transformToList(breedsResponse) {
    const {message: breeds} = breedsResponse;
    const breedMainNames = Object.keys(breeds);
    return breedMainNames.reduce((acc, mainName) => {
        const subNames = breeds[mainName];
        if(subNames.length === 0) {
            acc.push(mainName)
        } else {
            const combinedNames = subNames.map(name => `${name} ${mainName}`);
            acc.push(...combinedNames);
        }

        return acc;
    }, [])
};
```